# How can i turn container to Floatting action button

Tags: flutter

i am developin app i just got some of those code from an app  i just need to cart page button make a floating action button this button shows how many products in cart also i want to  do this if counter=0 i need to hide that FloatingActionButton if they added item to basket just show that time if you have any suggestions thanks a lot for now

```
'class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final CartListBloc bloc = BlocProvider.getBloc<CartListBloc>();
// TODO: implement build
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.listStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          List<FoodItem> foodItems = snapshot.data;
          int length = foodItems != null ? foodItems.length : 0;

          return buildGestureDetector(length, context, foodItems);
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
   );
 }

  GestureDetector buildGestureDetector(
    int length, BuildContext context, List<FoodItem> foodItems) {
  return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    if (length > 0) {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Cart()));
    } else {
      return;
    }
  },
  child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
    child: Text(length.toString()),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.yellow[800], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
  ),
 );
```

}'

[image: this is the screenshot of the app the container is on the top left]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a stateful widget and not a stateless one. If you are using VS code, it can actually do it for you automatically.

Once you have that, one variable will be "length".

```
String length;

void initState() {
    length=0;
}
```

Whenever you increment it up, you have to call...

```
setState(() {
      length+=1;
    });
```

or down...

```
setState(() {
      length-=1;
    });
```

your floating action button will be...

```
(length==0)?
Container():
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Cart()));
  },
  child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
    child: Text(length.toString()),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.yellow[800], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
  ),
 );
```

This means that if the cart length is 0, it will show an empty container.
If the cart is not 0, it will show a button with length

Comment: there is nothing happened in my button i just want to hold button on the right bottom corner